# Auto height virtual list for Mobiles to display large list

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement where I have to display large list of items that may have different heights and also items will be adding to end of list dynamically. Previously I have written my own virtual list and that performed very well in Desktop browsers, but I observed flickering in with that list in Safari browser as I was doing a lot many things on scroll. As safari adds effects while scrolling it was conflicting with native scroll effects. I have found an interesting way of inserting and removing nodes while scrolling [here](https://github.com/sergi/virtual-list/blob/master/vlist.js). But this is designed for lists that has fixed height elements, not for auto height elements(Even solution I have implemented) because  at the start we calculate the total height like below

```
 this.totalRows = config.totalRows || (config.items && config.items.length);

 var scroller = VirtualList.createScroller(itemHeight * this.totalRows);
 this.container = VirtualList.createContainer(width, height);
 this.container.appendChild(scroller);
```

And while scrolling we find scroll item as below

```
 var first = parseInt(scrollTop / itemHeight);
```

But, this is what scaring me because for auto height elements and I completely clueless on `how can I calculate first item`, and `how to find total height of dummy scroller`.

Anybody has implemented this kind of solution for mobiles before, and are there any alternatives to this approach or any plugins available?

Comment: Demo on jsfiddle.net please.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be able to do correct calculating by always run a loop through each elemnt to get every elements actual height. Auto height elements still has a height. Make sure to do some real testing and there are different ways to calculate height. I do it in jquery using outerHeight to make sure it calcualtes with padding. It would be easier if you shared some hardcoded html/js and point on a specific problem with the height.